# Laravel 5.3 return result only if another row in the same table doesn't exist

Tags: laravel

Basically I have a followers table in which user_id and followable_id is stored. If for example user A follows user B a record is created. And if B follows A then a new record is created. I need to return result only if A is following B, but if B is also following A then do not return anything.

I tried various solutions non of them worked. Maybe someone could point me to the right direction thanks.

EDIT:
This works however it's ugly hacky and I want to avoid this:

```
$iFollows = Followers::where('user_id', '=', $currentUser->id)->get();
$myFollowers = Followers::where('followable_id', '=', $currentUser->id)->get();


    foreach($myFollowers as $key => $value){

        foreach($iFollows as $iFollow){

            if($value->user_id == $iFollow->followable_id){
                $myFollowers->forget($key);
            }
        }
    }
```

Database Structure:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve same thing but with laravel query builder?

User implements trait called Followable

```
trait Followable
{
    /**
     * Collection of followers attached to this object
     *
     * @return Query|Collection
     */
    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(
            User::class,        // related
            'followable',       // name
            'followers',      // table
            'followable_id',    // foreignKey
            'user_id'           // otherKey
        )->where('status', 1)->withPivot('created_at', 'updated_at');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function followings()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(
            User::class,        // related
            'followable',       // name
            'followers',      // table
            'user_id',    // foreignKey
            'followable_id'           // otherKey
        )->where('status', 1)->withPivot('created_at', 'updated_at');
    }
```

Comment: any clue on the database structure?

Comment: How you try? Give us example code.

Comment: https://s33.postimg.cc/9dv4lu8of/sdsd.png Database structure.

Comment: Have you got relationships set up between `User` and `Follower`?

Comment: Hi @John, so you want to get the followers of the `currentUser` who doesn't follow you back?

Comment: @aceraven777 Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For me I think your code looks ok, just add comment to the code for the coder to easily understand what is happening.

I have a one query here to get what you're looking for, get all followers who doesn't follow you back:

```
$myFollowers = Followers::selectRaw('followers.*')
    ->leftJoin('followers AS followers2', 'followers.user_id', '=', 'followers2.followable_id')
    ->where('followers.followable_id', '=', $currentUser->id)
    ->whereNull('followers2.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have finally solved my issue with this method:

```
/**
 * Class FollowableTrait
 * @package App\Traits
 */
trait Followable
{
    /**
     * @param  array $ids 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function newFollowers($ids)
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(
            User::class,        // related
            'followable',       // name
            'followers',      // table
            'followable_id',    // foreignKey
            'user_id'           // otherKey
        )->where('status', 1)->whereNotIn('user_id', $ids)->withPivot('created_at', 'updated_at');;
    }
```

Then in my controller:

```
$ids = $currentUser->followings()->pluck('followable_id')->toArray();
$newFollowers = $currentUser->newFollowers($ids)->get();
```